# Determine how many positive integers are $\leq 500$ and divisible by at least one between $6$, $10$ and $25$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

Determine how many positive integers are $\leq 500$ and divisible by at least one between $6$, $10$ and $25$.

I used sets to do this exercise.

$B_1 = 500/6 = 83$

$B_2 = 500/10 = 50$

$B_3 = 500/25 = 20$

$B_1 \cap B_2 = 16$

$B_1 \cap B_3 = 6$

$B_2 \cap B_3 = 10$

$B_1 \cap B_2 \cap B_3 = 3$

$|B_1| + |B_2| + |B_3| - 2|B_1 \cap B_2| -2|B_1 \cap B_3| -2|B_2 \cap B_3| +3|B_1 \cap B_2 \cap B_3| = 83 + 50 + 20 - 32 - 12 - 20 + 9 = 98$

Please tell me if I made mistakes, thank you.

Comment: Why are the 2's and the 3's multiplied in the last step

Comment: @Manthanein I don't know, I just used this formula from another exercise which was similar but I don't think it works in this exercise.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Sorry.

Comment: Also, since $\operatorname{lcm}(6, 25) = 150$, you should have $$|B_1 \cap B_3| = \left\lfloor \frac{500}{150} \right\rfloor = \left\lfloor \frac{10}{3} \right\rfloor = 3$$

Comment: Shouldn't it be  $|B_1| + |B_2| + |B_3| - |B_1 \cap B_2| -|B_1 \cap B_3| -|B_2 \cap B_3| +|B_1 \cap B_2 \cap B_3|$

Answer (score 1):

Hint. By [Inclusion–exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), it should be
$$|B_1\cup B_2\cup B_3|=|B_1| + |B_2| + |B_3| - |B_1 \cap B_2| -|B_1 \cap B_3| -|B_2\cap B_3| +|B_1 \cap B_2 \cap B_3|.$$

P.S. Note that $|B_1\cap B_3|=\lfloor 500/\text{lcm}(6,25)\rfloor=\lfloor 500/150\rfloor=3$.

Comment: So the correct answer is 124 ?

Comment: No, It should be 127.

Answer (score 0):

It should be
$$|B_1 \cup B_2 \cup B_3| = |B_1|+|B_2|+|B_3|-|B_1 \cap B_2|-|B_1 \cap B_3|-|B_2 \cap B_3| + |B_1 \cap B_2 \cap B_3|$$
And it is called Inclusion-Exclusion Principle in case you want to learn it properly. But size of the sets are correct (except from $|B_1 \cap B_3|$) so you can proceed after knowing the correct formula.

Comment: Ok, so 124 should be the answer, right?

Comment: Check the calculation for $|B_1 \cap B_3|$.

Comment: Aw, yes it should be $|B_1 \cap B_3| = 3$.

Comment: @sdnaksn after the correction the answer is $127$.